# Convex Sets in Topology

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres Topology, he uses the term 'A subset Y of X that is convex in X' in page 91. I couldn't find a definition for it inside the book and the definitions outside the book(on the internet) seems to be unrelated. Can someone give me the definition Munkres uses?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to theorem 16.4 when he writes: Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology; let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ which is convex in $X$.

This means the following: Let $Y \subset X$. Now, if $a,b \in Y$ and $a < c <b$, then $c \in Y$.